# Timestamp string length

Tags: c#, string, timestamp, utc, string-length

If I did this

```
// Default implementation of UNIX time of the current UTC time
TimeSpan ts = DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
string myResult = "";
myResult = Convert.ToInt64(ts.TotalSeconds).ToString();
```

What is the maximum string length of myResult and is it always the same size?

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Just because Neo needs to know how far the rabbit hole goes to decide if to take a red pill or blue pill.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

An Int64 is a signed 64-bit integer, which means it has a range of values from `−9,223,372,036,854,775,808` to `9,223,372,036,854,775,807`.

Since `toString` doesn't format its output with commas, the longest possible value of the string would be `−9223372036854775808` which is 20 characters long.

Now, since this is representing a UNIX timestamp we need to take into consideration what would be considered a "reasonable" date to return. As I write this, a current UNIX timestamp would be something close to `1292051460`, which is a 10-digit number.

Assuming a maximum length of 10 characters gives you a range of timestamps from `-99999999` to `9999999999`. This gives you a range of dates from "Mon, 31 Oct 1966 14:13:21 GMT" to "Sat, 20 Nov 2286 17:46:39 GMT". Note that I'm including the negation symbol as a character in the lower bound, which is why the lower bound is so much closer to the epoch than the upper bound.

If you're not expecting dates before Halloween 1966 or after late November 2286, you can reasonably assume that the length of the string won't exceed 10 characters. If you are expecting dates outside of this range (most likely pre-1966 rather than post-2286), you can expect to see an 11 character string. I wouldn't expect any more than that.

That's the *maximum* number of characters to expect; it could be shorter.

Comment: Perfect answer, so we can use these to generate unique ID's that has 10 digits, It comes handy when you are dealing with ID generators. Its already an ID and it can be converted into Time anytime thus eliminating the need to store date values.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the code is used far into the future it would be the maximum length of an Int64.

For example, right now that value is 1292022273 so the length would be 10.

You can find a calculator that includes the seconds here http://www.timeanddate.com/date/duration.html

Comment: No, I think sometime in the 24th century it will go over 9999999999 seconds and become 11 long. So I guess it depends on what you mean by "always". Your code probably won't be around by then.

Comment: 24th century i will be dead, and surely enough someone would of solved the problem before this time!

Comment: I like simple answers

Answer (score 1):

If you stick with `Convert.ToInt64()` with no formatting, then your maximum length will be **20**, because the minimum `Int64` is `-9223372036854775808` (the negative sign requires an extra character).  In practice, however, it will not utilize the entire range afforded by `Int64` due to limitations in `TimeSpan` and `DateTime`.

And, no, the length of `myResult` will not always be the same, but can range from 1 to 20.  It just depends on the current value of `Convert.ToInt64(ts.TotalSeconds)`.

Comment: Technically the maximum length would be 20 characters, since Int64s are unsigned. ;)

Comment: @AgentConundrum - You are correct; I've updated the answer to account for negative values since Int64s are *signed* ;-)

Comment: aaargh... and it's too late to edit my comment. I'm doomed to look like an idiot for all eternity! DOOOOMED!

Answer (score 0):

To get max size of the TimeSpan try to use this code:

```
var maxValue = Convert.ToInt64(TimeSpan.MaxValue).ToString();
```

Hope it will help you with your question! Good luck!

Best regards, Dima.